# Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome shell stuck in fall back mode - Acer 5830TG Notebook

Tags: gnome, 12.10, nvidia, acer

One of my friends is using Ubuntu 12.10 Unity for some time. And finally he decided to try gnome shell. Hence he installed gnome shell and now while logging into gnome shell (from login screen) this weird thing occurs. Its falling back to old gnome. Tried restarting the laptop but still didnt work. He has Nvidia Gforce GT 540M graphic card. Didnt install any proprietary drivers. Tried disabling the graphic card in BIOS as well. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Install a driver for nvidia using jocky-gtk

Comment: @shantanu he will not see any extra driver in `jocky-gtk` as this is optimus enabled graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

540m is a optimus enabled graphics card.

Execute following

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Now reboot,the issue will be resolved.

To properly use this card see [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/35775)